# How can I insert or create users to Firebase auth from Excel File?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an MS Excel file which contains the following columns: email and password. And I have more than a 1000rows! I want to know if there is a way to insert this data into Firebase auth or if there is a bulk creation method using my Excel file.

Any help is really appreciated!. Thanks

Comment: No such tool is provided by Firebase.  You will have to write code to get this job done, or do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSV file as explained in the documentation of the [`auth:import`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-import) Firebase CLI command: it allow importing user accounts into Firebase projects.

So you can easily adapt your Excel file in order to include the UID and the [password Hash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#password_hash_parameters) and Salt and export it as [CSV](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#CSV).